# Solution of cubic equation

Tags: polynomials

Assume that following holds for some reals $A,B$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[A k(n-k) + B \right]= n^3$$
The problem is to evaluate the coefficients $A,B$.
These coefficients are $A = 6, B = 1$, however, I have a problem to evaluate them, my try:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[A kn - A k^2 + B\right] = n^3$$
$$ A \sum_{k=1}^{n} kn - A \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} B = n^3$$
$$ An \sum_{k=1}^{n} k- A \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 + Bn = n^3$$
Furthermore, by means of Faulhaber's formula we replace the sums
$$ An \frac{n^2+n}{2} - A \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 +n}{6} + Bn = n^3$$
$$ A\frac{n^3+n^2}{2} - A \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 +n}{6} + Bn = n^3$$
$$ A\frac{3n^3+3n^2}{6} - A \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 +n}{6} + Bn = n^3$$
$$ A\frac{n^3+n}{6} + Bn = n^3 \ \color{red}{*}$$
Multiply both part by $6$ and moving $6n^3$ to the left part gives
$$ An^3 + An + 6Bn - 6n^3 = 0$$
Since that $n>0$, we have to solve the following system of equations
$$n^3(A - 6) + n(6B + A) = 0$$
$$A - 6 = 0$$
$$6B + A = 0$$
Which gives
$$A = 6$$
$$B = -1$$
Which is wrong answer.
Please, advice on my mistakes.
Moreover, please advice on the case
$$\sum_{k=1}^n Ak^2(n-k)^2 + Bk(n-k) + C = n^5$$

Update: as It mentioned in comments, there is a wrong plus in $A\frac{n^3+n}{6} + Bn = n^3$, if we fix it, it goes well

$$ An^3 - An + 6Bn - 6n^3 = 0$$
Since that $n>0$, we have to solve the following system of equations
$$n^3(A - 6) + n(6B - A) = 0$$
$$A - 6 = 0$$
$$6B - A = 0$$
Which gives
$$A = 6$$
$$B = 1$$

Comment: I have marked the line where you have made an error. You should have a minus sign there.

Comment: @Tavish true. Thank you a lot

Comment: @PKK the best ways is to plug some random values of n and then solve for A,B

Comment: This is not a cubic equation, actually. It's a polynomial identity, where you look for coefficients such that the identity is fullfilled. Just like partial fractions, for instance

Comment: put $n=1$ and $n=2$